# Storm missing resources folder when deploying JAR topology

Tags: java, python, sbt, apache-storm

I'm trying to deploy a topology that uses a MultiLang Bolt (written in Python):

```
builder.setBolt("avro-parser", new AvroBolt(), 3).shuffleGrouping("main-kafka-spout");
builder.setBolt("nlp-analyzer", new NLPBolt("/python/analyzer/audio_parser.py"), 2).shuffleGrouping("avro-parser");
```

I can submit the topology without problems, but checking the log files I see this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error when launching multilang subprocess

    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess.launch(ShellProcess.java:89) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt.prepare(ShellBolt.java:131) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__7953$fn__7966.invoke(executor.clj:792) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__625.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/python" (in directory "/var/lib/storm/supervisor/stormdist/sintonea-topology-main-22-1472285031/resources"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess.launch(ShellProcess.java:82) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess
```

Of course, I've noticed that I don't have a "resources" folder in the specified log trace:

> /var/lib/storm/supervisor/stormdist/sintonea-topology-main-22-1472285031/resources

If you do a "ls" command in that directory, you'll see it:

```
stormcode.ser  stormconf.ser  stormjar.jar
```

Why storm is not creating a resources folder in that directory?

I have two resources folders inside src/main/resources:

- schema: contains avro scheme files
- python: contains the python code

These folders are copied into the JAR in the root directory, instead of a /resources folder.

How is that possible? I have an AvroBolt that is using an schema in this way and it's not giving any problem (tested with a DummyBolt instead of MultiLang Bolt):

```
_schema = parser.parse(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/schema/caller_request.avsc"));
```

**EDIT**

I've moved my resources folder to

> baseDirectory.value / "multilang"

After reading this:

http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Creating-a-new-Storm-project.html

Now the resource folder is created and copied, but I'm still having the same issue:

```
Serializer Exception:
/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/resources/python/analyzer/audio_parser.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**EDIT 2**

I've found a workaround (create two resources folders at different levels):

1. Create a multilang/resources in the parent directory of src (one level up). Copy the python folder inside: {base-directory}/multilang/resources/python/*.py
2. Leave intact the folder src/main/schema: {base-directory}/src/main/resources/schema/caller_request.avsc.

And added this to my build.sbt:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += { baseDirectory.value / "multilang" }
unmanagedClasspath in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "multilang"
```

And set up my ShellBot as (ignoring the word "resources" or "/" in path):

```
NLPBolt nlpBolt = new NLPBolt("python/analyzer/audio_parser.py");
```

And:

```
_schema = parser.parse(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/schema/caller_request.avsc"));
```

It seems to work, but I don't like this solution. Any thoughts?

**EDIT 3**

By the way, this code:

```
import storm
#from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from es_tagger import SpanishTagger

config = utils.load_json('python/analyzer/data/config.json')

class AudioParserBolt(storm.BasicBolt):
```

Produces the following error:

```
Serializer Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/analyzer/audio_parser.py", line 27, in <module>
    class AudioParserBolt(storm.BasicBolt):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BasicBolt'
```

Comment: A copy/paste of storm.py code alongside my python script did the trick for this last issue. I'll post this all the 3 edits as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is basically what I did to get it working:

1. Create folder ${basedir}/multilang/resources --> copy python code inside.
2. Remove python code from ${basedir}/src/main/resources and leave only the Avro schemes.
3. Add to the build.sbt file:

> unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += { baseDirectory.value / "multilang" }
>       unmanagedClasspath in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "multilang"

4. Download storm.py from https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-multilang/python/src/main/resources/resources/storm.py and copy/paste it into ${basedir}/multilang/resources/python folder.
5. In the Python code, comment or remove any print instruction (provokes Java exceptions parsing the tuples because print writes into standard output).
6. In case your Python process is a bit slow (mine is an NLP process and requires a little bit to setup the first time), tell your topology to wait a little more:

> config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_SUBPROCESS_TIMEOUT_SECS, );

7. And a lot of trial and error =)

Any time you need to use an external file in your Python code, like a configuration file, call it like this (the parent directory will be the multilang/resources we created before):

> config = utils.load_json('python/analyzer/data/config.json')

Comment: I have a maven project with Storm and Ruby and I get the same error as you. But I do not have a `build.sbt` file. Can you help me to fix it or how can I create it to have this up and running?